# How to create a sharepoint 2010 template that will dynamically update its child sites

Tags: sharepoint, templates, sharepoint-2010

I recently created a site in Sharepoint 2010, and I have saved it as a template.  I'm able to apply this template to new sites, which is great.  I can then add new data to each site individually.  However, my problem is that if I want to change something on every child site, I would have to go through manually and do so.  Is there any way that I can create a template that will work dynamically so that I can make changes to the original and all the child sites will inherit these changes?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not how you are requesting. When a site is created it uses a site template, including your own custom site template. Once a site has been created there is no way to reapply a site template to that existing site. You could use PowerShell to update a series of existing sites but the commands would get quite complex.

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed new site collections using a globally deployed template and you change that template using SharePoint designer, you should not have any issues and changes will be automatically applied to child sites unless you change master page.